# How to I upload and install non-PyPI packages to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application I want to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, and it has a dependency on an internal package hosted in my company's private PyPI repo. Obviously, including this package in `requirements.txt` will do no good when I deploy it, since Elastic Beanstalk will not have access to the private PyPI in order to download it. I thought I'd get around this problem by downloading my package and including it in the source bundle, but I cannot figure out how to get the deploy to install this bundled package.

If my source bundle contains:

```
.
├── application.py
├── requirements.txt
└── special-private-package-1.0-cp27-none-any.whl
```

and my `requirements.txt` includes the following:

```
special-private-package-1.0-cp27-none-any.whl
```

My deploy fails because it cannot find the file `special-private-package-1.0-cp27-none-any.whl`. Looking at the logs, I see why: the working directory when running `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt` is not the directory containing `requirements.txt`, which means the relative path to my wheel cannot be resolved.

How do I configure this so that I can upload and install these private packages?

Comment: I think 'Vendoring' would help you there. 
Check this: https://medium.com/underdog-io-engineering/vendoring-python-dependencies-with-pip-b9eb6078b9c0

Comment: @Raphael This is almost exactly what I'm doing, but it fails because it relies on the local file being referenced relative to requirements.txt, but the pip install that elastic beanstalk uses is not in the same directly as requirements.txt, so the relative paths resolve to the wrong location.

Comment: Oh, I see. The prefered way to avert that is using virtualenv. Did you try to follow the EBS python tutorial from aws, chapter 'Setting up a virtual Python environment'? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-common-steps.html#Setting up a virtual Python environment

Comment: @Raphael I feel like you're not actually reading my question. I don't see how that's relevant at all to the problem I described. The virtualenv in that article is just a way to ensure you define your requirements.txt in a clean environment, but that does not address the problem I have with a private package.

Comment: You can pack your dependencies, private or not inside a docker image and deploy to EBS as well.